# How do I change my "persona" in a group chat?

Tags: macos, ios, messages, apple-id, messages-in-icloud

I recently switched from T-mobile to US Mobile, which doesn't have free/included international use in Mexico and Canada (where I travel often). That means when I go to Canada I'll need to get an ad hoc eSIM for that trip and will have a different number as a result.

For ease of messaging, I'd like to change my membership in various group chats I'm in to use my AppleID for messaging rather than my phone number. I couldn't figure out how to do that. My first attempt was:

1. On my mac, add my AppleID email address to a group chat (saw that I appeared in the 'other people' list, which I presumed meant I was good for step 2)
2. left the group chat from my mac. This didn't leave me in the chat with my email like I'd hoped.
3. Got another member of the group chat to add me back in using my AppleID. Now I'm back in the chat, but Mac messages no longer has a text entry bar for me. It works fine on my phone, though.

Is there a better way to do this? Change my group chats over to my address I mean? Or barring that, how can I at least use this chat on my mac again? I've tried reboots, signing out of iCloud/iMessage on the mac, re-syncing messages in iCloud, etc. I'm stuck here - what's going on?

Comment: I would use something like Signal (app) instead